# Putting Maven profiles into external files?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have several Maven profiles, which should not all be available on all machines. So I don't want to put them into the super pom in the root directory.

However, as far as I can see there is no way to put Maven 3 build profiles into different files and include them during runtime using activation rules and command line parameters.

Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maven 3 there is no possibility to put profiles into an external file. In earlier version (Maven 2.2.1 there exists a profiles.xml).